# Rundeck job fails with PermissionDenied UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: powershell-2.0, rundeck

I have a job in a rundeck that connects to windows machine by some domain network's user credentials and runs the script that copies some folder from another machine in the domain network.
Connection to windows node done by WinRM.

When I run that script by rundeck job it fails with error

```
[ERROR  ]  Test-Path : Access is denied
10:43:56    At E:\scripts\site_backup.ps1:20 char:10
10:43:56    + if(-not (Test-Path $BackupDirectory)) {
10:43:56    +          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~    

PermissionDenied: (\\some.path.local\dprr...rw-tests-pq:String) [Test-Path], UnauthorizedAccessException
```

However, if I run that script under the same user connecting by RDP to that machine it works fine.

I suspect WinRM service does not have enough privileges. Maybe I am wrong. How can I resolve that issue? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's "double hop" PowerShell problem. You can check a full explanation [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/enable-powershell-second-hop-functionality-with-credssp/), and [here](https://serverfault.com/a/495960) a good approach. Also [here](https://serverfault.com/a/495589) a good wokaround.

Comment: thanks,  seems you are righ.
But is there anyway to configure rundeck? Also if it runs on Linux machine.

Answer (score 1):

As @MegaDriver68k said, it was "double hop" Powershell issue. In order to overcome that on Rundeck it was required:

1. Set

> `winrm-authtype: credssp`

on node yaml file (I added node to rundeck via adding yaml file)

2. Install required pip package on Rundeck Machine

> `pip install pywinrm[credssp]`

3. Enable credSSP athentication Group Policy for "WinRM client" and "WinRM Service" on Windows Node. More details about it you may find out [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/winrm/installation-and-configuration-for-windows-remote-management?redirectedfrom=MSDN#configuring-winrm-with-group-policy)