# Running a powershell from rundeck(linux) display different result

Tags: bash, powershell, rundeck

I'm trying to run a powershell script from rundeck(linux), If I run the script locally[Deletes some files from multiple terminal servers](Windows server) it is working as expected however if I call it from rundeck server(winrm configured) it seems that the script cant access the remote folders I'm trying to access.

I tried running the script using the same user but still shows different result.

Script bellow:

```
$userAD = "someuser"
$servers = Get-Content C:\TSList.csv
$Folder = "c$\Users\$userAD\"
$TSFolderShare = "\\sharepath"

Write-Output "#####Start of script#####"
Write-output `n
Write-output "Checking if $userAD user profile exist in Terminal servers..."

sleep -seconds 1

foreach ($server in $servers) {

Test-Path "\\$server\$Folder" -PathType Any
Get-ChildItem "\\$server\$Folder" 

    if (Test-Path "\\$server\$Folder" -PathType Any) {
        Write-output  "Resetting user profile in $server.."
                   Get-ChildItem "\\$server\$Folder" -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue  | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue 
        
        sleep -seconds 1
        Write-output "Done." 

        if( (Get-ChildItem "\\$server\$Folder" | Measure-Object).Count -eq 0)
             {
                Write-output "Done." 
             }
        
    }
    else
    {
        Write-output  "Resetting user profile in $server.."
        sleep -seconds 1
        Write-output  "User profile does not exist in $server."          
        #Write-output "\\$server\$Folder does not exist in $server!" -ForegroundColor Red
    }
```

}

EDIT: It seems my problem is when running my script from another script with RunAS.

Below I'm trying to access a folder from another server using ps script, but since I want to integrate this to Rundeck I need to call my ps script from my linux server using python. I did a test running the ps script directly and calling the test path script using another script with RunUs using the same user I used to run the script manually

1. Scenario 1
   Running PS script via separate PS script with RunAS(my_account)

   $username = "my_account"
   $password = "my_password"
   $secstr = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.SecureString
   $password.ToCharArray() | ForEach-Object {$secstr.AppendChar($_)}
   $cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $username, $secstr

   Invoke-Command -FilePath "C:\testpath.ps1" -Credential $cred -Computer localhost

(C:\testpath.ps1) Content below:

`Test-Path "\\server\c$\Users\myaccount\"`

result:

Access is denied
+ CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (\server\c$\Users\myaccount:String) [Test-Path], UnauthorizedAccessException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ItemExistsUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.TestPathCommand
+ PSComputerName        : localhost

False

2. Scenario 2
   Running C:\testpath.ps1 directly as my_account

`Test-Path "\\server\c$\Users\myaccount\"`

result:
True

Comment: Hi, What message are you seeing when the script is executed from Rundeck? Can you share it? (please change or hide any sensitive information). Regards!

Comment: Can you share your job definition to check how the script is defined? Also your windows node definition (resources.xml) to take a look. Thanks! – MegaDrive68k 37 mins ago

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the response I updated the post, basically my original script will delete the content of a directory from another terminal server, if I run the script manually(via ISE or ./) it is working however if I call the script using another script with the path I'm trying to access is denied, I also defined to use the same user as what I used when running it manually. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're facing a double-hop issue with Rundeck and Powershell,  [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/enable-powershell-second-hop-functionality-with-credssp/) the explanation. That's asked before, take a look a [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63086240/rundeck-job-fails-with-permissiondenied-unauthorizedaccessexception), and [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/493170/why-can-a-domain-admin-run-a-powershell-cmd-locally-but-connecting-over-winrm-w/495589#495589) a good workaround. Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63159299/10426011) to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

I used session configuration in powershell to solve the issue. This way allows you to tie a credential to a PowerShell session configuration and reuse this configuration for all future connections.

https://4sysops.com/archives/solve-the-powershell-multi-hop-problem-without-using-credssp/

Thanks a lot!